# Immediately starting new UIViewController from a viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, awakefromnib

When the UIViewController starts, I want to start another UIViewController immediately.
This doesn't work:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib {
    UIViewController *newcontroller = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    ...
    [self presentModalViewController:newcontroller animated:YES];
}
```

In order for this to work, I have to do afterDelay for a method, like so:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib {
    [self performSelector:@selector(startNewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    [super init];
}
-(void) startNewController {
    UIViewController *newcontroller = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to get it to work without delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `startNewController` in your `viewDidAppear` method instead, that happens because your viewController is not totally loaded when you try to present the modal viewController, so that's why it works when you wait.

Comment: No, doesn't work too. Only afterDelay works with viewDidLoad.

Comment: You're right, a little confusion, I've corrected my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Practically, you should not plan your application architecture which forces you to do such implementations. Though, I can understand there are times where you have no way out..

I'd say:
best solution for your case is to call your controller from

> viewDidAppear

or

> viewWillAppear

Comment: I'll try to explain the need for such implementation. The root controller acts as a loader with "Download", etc. It will be shown while the other controller with graphics is loaded that performs the function menu. When choosing a menu item, I unload the current controller and run through the root controller the new one. Hope explained clearly.